# Does low battery level stop the location service or make it fail to fetch the location?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, battery, location-services, batterylevel

Some of my users ran into an issue where they couldn't fetch the location using Location Service.
In the screenshots they sent me, i noticed that the battery level was really low, like 2-5%.
My question is, does iOS stop the location service when the device is running out of battery?

Thanks

Comment: What do you exactly mean that the users can't fetch the location? Any error message from `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: user couldn't see that error message. And i haven't been able to reproduce it myself. Looks like the CLLocationManager failed to fetch the current location for some reason. Would need to post a rollbar log to see.

Answer (score 1):

> does iOS stop the location service when the device is running out of battery

It certainly might. The GPS is one of the highest power draws of all the sensors. Turning it off would make a lot sense. See also Apple's own statements about low power mode:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205234

Note that if this is the case, it would hardly be an issue with your app. Your app might use a lot of battery, which could be a problem; but if location services itself is affected, *all* map/navigation apps would be affected.

Comment: our users are actively using our camera based app like 24/7, so that would be using a lot of battery for sure

Comment: You might want to think about ways to reduce energy usage. Apple provides lots of advice and analytical tools in this area. But you probably already know that. :)

Comment: Thanks @matt. Not sure what we can do that much as the camera usage is the most importance feature of the app. I am open to any suggestion :)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't stop background work, because our app still sends some events. iOS may reduce some power on sensors, so GPS coordinates come with bad accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Low Power Mode (the one that turns the battery icon yellow) does several things to reduce the battery usage of your device. This probably includes the accuracy and refresh rate of the GPS.

If you're requesting a location with a high level of accuracy, the system might either take too long and timeout or just decide not to fulfill that request since the hit on the battery would be too much.

Comment: yeah. i am waiting on my phone on low battery condition, and see if it causes the issue